# Cannot change sftp remote directory using SharpSSH in C#?

Tags: c#, sharpssh

I've tried every combination of a path string that I can think of but still I get back `"The requested file does not exist"?`  I've searched the internet for the past few hours and I cannot find an example.  Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong.  I've tried the following already.

Using the `ls` command from the root.  I get a list of the directories and files available.  So say it returned the following list.

`Outbound
Inbound`

I've so far tried.

`cd ./Inbound/

cd /Inbound/

cd Inbound

cd //Inbound//

cd //Inbound

cd Inbound/

cd ../Inbound/

cd \Inbound\

cd \\Inbound\\

cd ..\\Inbound\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to do some maintenance work on the SharpSSH library (bitbucket.org/mattgwagner/SharpSSH) but I can honestly say I'd recommend you check out sshnet.codeplex.com for a properly designed and better functioning library. The original SharpSSH was a DIRECT port of a Java library to .NET 1.1, I believe, and suffers from the translation.